# How to copy the vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

Task: I need a copy vector. Then I need to go and compare each element in the original vector to find if it has any duplicate fruit_name. If yes, I will copy that element into the copy vector.

```
struct fruit_t
{
    char fruit_name[MAX_LENGTH];  // name of fruit
    float quantity; // in lbs
    float price;          // price tag of the fruit
};
```

I did create a copy vector and use push_back to copy it (read somewhere on the internet). But when I cout the cpy vector, it show me that the cpy copied more than one time

```
vector <fruit_t> cpy;
int k = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
     for (int j = 1; j < count; j++){
            if (strcmp(fruit[i].fruit_name, fruit[j].fruit_name) == 0){
                   cpy.push_back(fruit[i]);
                   cout << cpy[i].fruit_name << endl;
               }
      }
}
```

The is what cpy[i].fruit_name give me. This is **wrong**

```
apples_gala
apples_gala
apples_gala
bananas
oranges_naval
oranges_naval
oranges_naval
apples_gala
apples_gala
apples_gala
apples_gala
apples_gala
raspberries
apples_gala
apples_gala
apples_gala
apples_gala
apples_gala
```

Input file

```
melon_cantaloupe     2.60     2.99
apples_gala          1.80     1.21
bananas              2.88     0.49
oranges_naval        2.63     0.99
apples_gala          3.00     1.21
raspberries          4.76     3.25
apples_gala          1.45     1.21
mango                4.07     1.20
blueberries          3.85     2.50
oranges_honeybell    4.20     1.08
apples_jazz          4.39     2.69
oranges_honeybell    4.22     1.08
```

Expected output:

```
apples_gala.........    
apples_jazz.........  
bananas.............  
blueberries.........  
mango............... 
melon_cantaloupe....  
oranges_honeybell...  
oranges_naval.......  
raspberries.........
```

Comment: `std::vector` has assignment operator which does this for free. Please use `std::string` not c-arrays for strings (it is a good practice).

Comment: What does it mean: `find the duplicate fruit_name from a file` What exactly is your task?

Comment: `char fruit_name[MAX_LENGTH];` are you forced to not use `std::string`?

Comment: Can you extrac a [mcve] and provide that here. I honestly don't know what you did, what happened and what you expected to happen. I also don't want to guess. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.. "_I need a copy vector_" - That's ok.  "_Then I need to go and compare each element in the original vector to find if it has any duplicate fruit_name_" -  Ok, if it has, then the copy will also have duplicates.."_If yes, I will copy that element into the copy vector._" - Then you'll have yet another duplicate in the copy. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Yes it was @Marek R

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm **guessing** the real question is "How do I populate a vector ONLY with elements that are duplicated in another vector?" -- but your guess is as good as mine.  This question is not at all clear.

Comment: Also, regarding "_This is **wrong**_" - Please show the input you used and the expected output too.

Comment: So I have a file that includes name, quantity, and price. My task is to go over each element in the vector then compare each of them. If I got a duplicated name, I will have to make that name become unique (and sum their quantity).

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to copy data from one container to the other, you can use the copy assignment operator in `std::vector` to get it done for you easily.

```cpp
vector<fruit_t> cpy = fruit;
```

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

But if your goal is to remove any duplicate entries, use `std::set`. Using vectors like that will slow you down.

```cpp
#include <set>

...
std::set<fruit_t> noDuplicateSet;

// This is how to insert.
for(auto itr = fruit.begin(); itr != fruit.end(); itr++)
    noDuplicateSet.insert(*itr);

// This is how to get the number of entries.
int noDuplicateCount = noDuplicateSet.size();
```

Now to use `std::set`, you need to have the `<` operator for the `fruit_t`. I would implement it like this,

```cpp
struct fruit_t
{
    char fruit_name[MAX_LENGTH];  // name of fruit
    float quantity; // in lbs
    float price;          // price tag of the fruit

    bool operator<(const fruit_t& other) const
    {
        return return strcmp(fruit_name, other.fruit_name) < 0;
    }
};
```

Bonus: If there isn't a reason not to use `std::string fruit_name;` instead of `char fruit_name[MAX_LENGTH];`, then go for it. Not saying that this is wrong but it could be more flexible that way.

Comment: I need a copy vector. Then I need to go and compare each element in the original vector to find if it has any duplicate fruit_name. If yes, I will copy that element into the copy vector.

Comment: @AnPhan If your goal is to eliminate any duplicate entries, just use `std::set<>` instead.

Comment: I also need to get the total quantity of the element that duplicates

Comment: @AnPhan Here's [an implementation](https://godbolt.org/z/1KzoWr) that roughly follows the advice given in D-RAJ's answer. The `operator<` is different and there are a few other things in there that I added. I commented in the code so you can see what it does.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes but since he's not using `std::string`, I couldn't find a method right away.

Comment: @TedLyngmo But then what if `quantity` and `price` changes? Shouldn't we take those two into account too?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Got you! Thanks for widening my knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking for how to find elements that appear multiple times in your vector and copy these element to a `cpy` vector.

In your `for`-loops you made the mistake that `i` and `j` are independant and therefore you compare `strcmp(fruit[i].fruit_name, fruit[j].fruit_name) == 0` for `i=j` which is not what you want.

Your problem is not easy to solve, but consider making a copy your vector, sorting it by name and then inspecting it. I think you should figure that out yourself.

To solve your entire problem as stated in the comment, you can use a combination of `std::sort`, `std::unique`, `std::erase` and `std::accumulate`.

Comment: how can you use unique for the struct? I did unique(fruit.begin(), fruit.end()) . It gave me bunch of error

Comment: You need to provide a comparison operator for your fruits, for example you can use a lambda expression.